# Spectral theory and and a problem in $\ell^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

> Be $\boldsymbol{X}=\ell^{2}$ and operators $A, B: \ell^{2} \rightarrow \ell^{2}$ by
> $$
> A x:=\left(\xi_{2}, \xi_{3}, \ldots\right), \quad B x:=\left(0, \xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \xi_{3}, \ldots\right)
> $$
> to $x=\left(\xi_{i}\right)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{2}$. Show that
> $$
> \sigma(A)=\sigma(B)=\mathbb{D},
> $$
> where $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq 1\} .$

I'm learning Basic spectral theory and i don't understand how deal with the problems i saw in the book.

Here i was thinking in finding the resolvent set $\rho(A) = \{\lambda \in K : A-\lambda I \text{ is invertible} \}$ and $K$ is scalar field, so i just have to find that $\rho(A) = K - \mathbb{D}$ because the spectrum is the complement. If my thought is correct, how can i solve this? or another hint to solve?. Thanks

Edit:
i found that $B$ is right shift operator and $\|B\| = 1$ also i know that the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is contained in the circle with radius $\|T\|$ and center $0$.
Here i have to questions: ¿Why the norm is $1$? ¿And the inverse, left shift operator has the same norma?

Then i have that $\sigma (A) \subset D$, now i have to proof the inverse $D \subset \sigma(A)$:
So taking $|\lambda| < 1 $ and the vector $x = (1, \lambda, \lambda^2,...)$ clearly $Ax = \lambda x$ so we have that the open disc is in the spectrum and we know that the spectrum is closed so $\sigma(A) = D$

Comment: You have to show some  more effort. What does bijective mean? When is $A-\lambda I$ injective? This part should be very straightforward.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gelfand transform? Although this should be doable from the definitions, it would be a useful tool in this scenario.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I change the definition to invertible, but i think that is the same. I was thinking when is injective but i dont understand, sorry.

Comment: @EthanMartin I dont know about the Gelfand Transform, sorry.